# Convert html entities to unicode characters via php mysql csv export

Tags: php

In my MySQL database this is a sample of an HTML entity that I have:

```
&Uacute;
```

When I export it through my script this is what I get:

```
Ãº
```

As you can see in my script I already have 'html_entity_decode' which should convert it appropriately to this (which is what I want):

```
Ú
```

Obviously, I am doing something wrong. I have exhausted other various scripts, solutions and otherwise have been trying to resolve this issue for over a day. Here is my PHP code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");

$sql="SELECT * FROM wtf";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Encoding: UTF-8");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="results.csv"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    fputcsv($fp,  array('Nome'));

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_map('html_entity_decode',array_values($row)), ',', '"');
    }
    die;
}

mysqli_close($link);
exit;
```

Could someone please help or at least point me in the right direction? Having taken on a project that requires European characters in the CSV results, it has been nothing less then a nightmare...

Comment: Which PHP version are you running on?

Comment: What do you get if you `echo html_entity_decode('&Uacute;');`?

Comment: PHP version 5.6.15.
If I `echo html_entity_decode('&Uacute;');` I get Ãº

Comment: Could you do these things: (1) make sure your PHP file is saved as UTF-8 file -- your text editor should have options to specify the character encoding; (2) put this before the `echo`: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` (3) try again to `echo html_entity_decode('&Uacute;');`. Any change?

Comment: The page has `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` as the first line at the top of the page. Echoing out the data always shows it correctly. The trick (or nightmare rather) is getting it to show correctly after being exported to a csv file.

Comment: Wait you said in the previous comment that the `echo` produced `Ãº`, now you say *Echoing out the data always shows it correctly*. I know that you want it exported to CSV file, but there can be many reasons for that problem, so I want to exclude some by asking you these questions. So can you answer again the previous question? Does it echo correctly or not?

Comment: Echoing to the browser always shows it correctly like this: `Ú` (The way I need it in the csv file). _Writing_ the data to a csv always results in this: `Ãº`. My apologies for the confusion. Surprisingly it doesn't work when I use `str_replace("Ãº", "ú", $string);` - right before writing it to the csv. I'm baffled this point.

Comment: Broken Sample: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

 header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
 header("Content-Encoding: UTF-8");
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="results.csv"');
 header('Pragma: no-cache');
 header('Expires: 0');

$i = 0; 

$row = array("&Uacute;", "B", "C");
  
  fputcsv($fp, array_values($row), ',', '"');
  
  $row[0] = str_replace("&Uacute;", "Ú", $row[0]);
  
  fputcsv($fp, array_values($row), ',', '"');

  $row[0] = html_entity_decode($row[0]);
  
  fputcsv($fp, array_values($row), ',', '"');`

Comment: Can you reduce the problem case to this? `echo "Ú";` (in browser) and `fputcsv($fp, array("´U"), ",", '"');` (in file, keeping the headers)? So in browser it is correct, in file it is wrong? I want to be sure the problem occurs even when you don't use `html_entity_decode`.

Comment: `echo "Ú"` is correct (in the browser). `fputcsv($fp, array("´U"), ",", '"');` shows up in the csv as `Â´U`. I'm assuming the accent location was intentional from you (`´U` instead of `Ú`)? Using `fputcsv($fp, array("Ú"), ",", '"');` results in `ÃšÃš`. An extrat `Ãš` has seem to be added for unknown reasons...

Comment: Thanks. Does the CSV look any different when you add this line just before the very first `fputcsv`: `fwrite($fp, "\xEF\xBB\xBF");`? It writes the magic *Byte Order Mark* at the start of the output.

Comment: Also make sure there is no empty line or white space before the opening `<?php` tag when you try the above suggestion.

Comment: Yes it does. Writing `fwrite($fp, "\xEF\xBB\xBF");` prior to retrieving/writing data to the csv (and with nothing else) displayed it correctly. It was enough for me to resolve the issue. Thank you very much trincot. I sincerely appreciate your help. I also hope this is able to assist someone in the future.

Comment: If an answer resolved your question, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're probably using a newer version of PHP, which will default to "UTF-8" when `html_entity_decode()` is called. Maybe try something like this:

Instead of this:

```
    fputcsv($fp, array_map('html_entity_decode',array_values($row)), ',', '"');
```

Try this:

```
    fputcsv($fp, call_user_func_array('html_entity_decode', array(array_values($row), ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1')), ',', '"');
```

Comment: Attempting `fputcsv($fp, call_user_func_array('html_entity_decode', array(array_values($row), ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1')), ',', '"');`
results in the following error (within the csv file): `<b>Warning</b>:  html_entity_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string  array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\web\_site\export.php</b> on line <b>26</b><br />`. The PHP version is 5.6.15. I have also tested different flavors of MS office for good measure (2003 and 2010 specifically) with the same baffling result...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by Excel misinterpreting the character encoding of your output.

An output like `Ãº` is an indication that a multi-byte character is being interpreted as two separate single byte characters. When instead of writing a string as CSV, you `echo` that same string, it is rendered correctly, so this means the problem is not in the string, as stored by PHP.

The header `Content-Encoding: UTF-8` does not find its way to Excel, so in order to make Excel aware of the UTF-8 encoding, output a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of the output:

```
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Encoding: UTF-8");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="results.csv"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    fwrite($fp, "\xEF\xBB\xBF"); // <--- add this
```

Secondly, things tend to also work better when you use a TAB character as separator instead of a comma, as in Europe some regional settings define the semi-colon as the separator (the comma being taken as decimal separator), and this will make all columns collapse into one. So write:

```
    fputcsv($fp,  array('Nome'), "\t", '"');
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_map('html_entity_decode',array_values($row)), "\t", '"');
    }
```